# How do I use gensim to vectorize these words in my dataframe so I can perform clustering on them?

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis, gensim

I am trying to do a clustering analysis (preferably k-means) of poetry words on a pandas dataframe. I am firstly trying to vectorize the words by using the word-to-vector feature in the gensim package. However, the vectors just come out with 0s, so my code is failing to translate the words into vectors. As a result, the clustering doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
# create a gensim model 
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(vector_size=100) 
# copy original pandas dataframe with poems
data = poems.copy(deep=True)
# get data ready for kmeans clustering
final_data = [] # empty list 
for i, row in data.iterrows(): 
    poem_vectorized = [] 
    poem = row['Main_text']
    poem_all_words = poem.split(sep=" ")
    for poem_w in poem_all_words: #iterate through list of words 
        try:
            poem_vectorized.append(list(model.wv[poem_w]))
        except Exception as e:
            pass
    try:
        poem_vectorized = np.asarray(poem_vectorized)
        poem_vectorized_mean = list(np.mean(poem_vectorized, axis=0))
    except Exception as e:
        poem_vectorized_mean = list(np.zeros(100))
        pass
    try:
        len(poem_vectorized_mean)
    except:
        poem_vectorized_mean = list(np.zeros(100))
    temp_row = np.asarray(poem_vectorized_mean)
    final_data.append(temp_row)
X = np.asarray(final_data)
print(X)
```

[image: Output]

At closer inspection of:

```
poem_vectorized.append(list(model.wv[poem_w]))
```

the problem seems to be this:
[image: syntax error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to use an **existing** model to get the semantic embeddings of the tokens and then cluster the words, right?

Because the way you set the model up you are preparing a new model for training, but then don't feed any training data to it and train it, so your model doesn't know any words and just always throws a KeyError when calling `model.wv[poem_w]`.

Use `gensim.downloader` to load an existing model (check out [their repository](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data#models) for a list of all available models):

```
import gensim.downloader as api
import numpy as np
import pandas

poems = pandas.DataFrame({"Main_text": ["This is a sample poem.", "This is another sample poem."]})
model = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-100")
```

Then use it to retrieve the vectors for all words the models knows:

```
final_data = []
for poem in poems['Main_text']:
    poem_all_words = poem.split()
    poem_vectorized = []
    for poem_w in poem_all_words:
        if poem_w in model:
            poem_vectorized.append(model[poem_w])
    poem_vectorized_mean = np.mean(poem_vectorized, axis=0)
    final_data.append(poem_vectorized_mean)
```

Or as list comprehension:

```
final_data = []
for poem in poems['Main_text']:
    poem_vectorized_mean = np.mean([model[poem_w] for poem_w in poem.split() if poem_w in model], axis=0)
    final_data.append(poem_vectorized_mean)
```

Which both will give you:

```
X = np.asarray(final_data)
print(X)
> [[-3.74696642e-01  3.73661995e-01  4.09943342e-01 -2.07784668e-01
    ...
    -1.85739681e-01 -7.07386672e-01  3.31366658e-01  3.31600010e-01]
   [-3.29973340e-01  4.13213342e-01  5.26199996e-01 -2.29261339e-01
    ...
    -1.25366330e-01 -5.87253332e-01  2.80240029e-01  2.56700337e-01]]
```

Note that attempting to get `np.mean()` on an empty list will throw an error so you might want to catch that in case there are poems which are empty or where all words are unknown to the model.